# How i can stop outgoin call in twilo

Tags: python, twilio

How can I stop an outgoing call in twilo? I must stop the call when the call status is equal to ringing. I want to make call bomber on python, but I don't know how to stop the call. It needs to be a free call because a call to Russia is very expensive =(

Comment: Even just getting a phone to ring does use Twilio’s service and might cost *them* money, so I wouldn’t count on being able to make “free calls” with them at all.

Comment: This  (Call Bomber) is a misuse of the Twilio platform and your account will be suspend. Please reference - https://www.twilio.com/legal/aup.

Comment: Yes, on the AUP it states it is forbidden to do: Using the Services in connection with unsolicited, unwanted, or harassing communications (commercial or otherwise), including, but not limited to, phone calls, SMS or MMS messages, chat, voice mail, video, email, or faxes.